# how to keep the old data fields when request.data does not include them

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created a model with fields `title` and `description`, and I have to always send a request with two fields even when I when I update only the `title` field. So, how can I make the view in which if the `description` field is missing then it keep the old `description`

```
class Paper(APIView):
    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        # TODO if any other field emtpy keep the old data
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = SerlizePaper(snippet, data=request.data)
        if(serializer.is_valid() and request.user in snippet.who_can_edite.all()):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is partial update.
[Partial Update DRF documentation link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates)

It can done in your case by

```
#note the partial keyword
serializer = SerlizePaper(snippet, data=request.data, partial=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take two approaches:

1. change your serializer

In your serializer,define the fields and "required=False" to both of
them:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False)
```

2. Use a PATCH Http method

   You can use PATCH method when you are calling your API and pass only
   the field that you want to change